# How can I insert multiple rows to MySQL using web API in a flutter mobile application

Tags: python, mysql, flutter, webapi, multiple-insert

I have been developing a mobile application in Flutter at Visual Studio Code environment.

For the backend layer I have developed a webapi in Python (in PyCharm env.)

For the database, I use MySQL (version 8.0.34).

I am currently able to communicate with the database properly for both get, insert, update or delete actions. But now I need to insert multiple rows (I have dynamic count rows, not a certain number of rows) into the database in a single action via the webapi. I don't want to send insert commands in a for loop or something like that.

I have searched over google but could not find an exact solution. Just few solutions didn't work.

I have tried to send multiple rows in a for loop but it made slow the application down. I need to deliver all the data to the mySql.
I have also found some solutions for a certain number of rows, that adding extra parameters. But in my project, the number of insert rows is not fixed.

Comment: Mysql definitely is able to accept multiple rows for insert (or even other action through transection). But it depends on how you designed your backend. If your backend does not support multiple insertion then you need to change something around or populate your database in other ways.

Comment: I build my webapi (backend service) with Python. It's working properly for get, insert , update, del etc.. But I don't know how to set up a stored procedure at MySQL database side. I guess, I can create arrays to be able to send the bulk rows if I can complete the stored procedure part at DB side.

Comment: Please review this URL  - https://www.bing.com/search?pglt=41&q=python+mysql+multiple+row+insert+example&cvid=26799741dd7e4c4a9dc1b79232ff472c&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIGCAEQABhAMgYIAhAAGEAyBggDEAAYQDIGCAQQABhAMgYIBRAAGEAyBggGEAAYQDIGCAcQABhAMgYICBAAGEDSAQkxMTI2N2owajGoAgCwAgA&FORM=ANNTA1&PC=U531